# Download XLS from highcharts-button-box using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, highcharts

I'm trying download xls file from highcharts-button-box but at the moment with good results.

This is de ID //*[@id="highcharts-h8ofb8h-686"]/svg

I'm tryings with this code but not working. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[name()='g'][6]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='image']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Download XLS']"))).click()
```

Comment: Please share the url or relevant html and error stack please?

Comment: <g class="highcharts-no-tooltip highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton highcharts-button-normal" stroke-linecap="round" style="cursor: pointer;" transform="translate(560,10)"><title>Menú de gráfica</title><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-button-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="24" height="22" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"></rect><path fill="#666666" d="M 6 6.5 L 20 6.5 M 6 11.5 L 20 11.5 M 6 16.5 L 20 16.5"

Comment: class="highcharts-button-symbol" data-z-index="1" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="3"></path><text x="0" data-z-index="1" y="15.5" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></text></g>

Comment: the error is: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

Comment: Hi @Su_80, The id is generated by Highcharts and it is different on each render, so you need to find a different way to get the button. Live example in pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tpbskyhL/